# Leibniz rule to find partial derivatives of a double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

For $F(u,v)=\displaystyle \int_0^u\int_0^vf(x,y) dxdy.$ How to evaluate $\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial u\partial v}$?

I tried to use the Leibniz rule and obtain

$F_v=\int_0^uf(v,y) dy$ and

$F_{vu}=f(v,u).$

I wonder my answer is correct or not? Because in my notes answer is $F_{vu}=f(u,v).$

Comment: You are right. One way to check is first to differentiate with respect to u and then with respect to v, which must give the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is. You've performed Leibniz rule well, and this the correct answer.